# How to fetch User from Database in Filter and add Id in jwt response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I want to return my id so i can use it, the question is how can i do that**

this is the default return  : 
{
    "role": "ROLE_XXXX",
    "succeed": "Berhasil Login",
    "username": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

**this is what i want :** 
{
    **"id": 123,**
    "role": "ROLE_XXXX",
    "succeed": "Berhasil Login",
    "username": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

and there's my code :

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain,
        final Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.info("successfulAuthentication");
    logger.info(auth);
    Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(auth.getAuthorities());
            String hasil=roles.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "");

    Map map = new HashMap(); 
    map.put("username", auth.getName());
    map.put("role", hasil);
    map.put("token", AuthenticationService.addToken(auth.getName()));
    map.put("succeed", "Berhasil Login");

    String authString = new Gson().toJson(map);


    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.print(authString);
    out.flush(); 

}
```

i'am try to call my model "User" so i can call like this
**map.put("id", user.getId());**
but it dosent work my model user cant call in protected void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Authentication` object to getName of the principal.

For example:
`auth.getName()` will give the name of the Principle. Use this name in order to retrieve `User` from the database and put the id accordingly.

In your filter, you can constructor inject the `ApplicationContext` and get bean of your `repository/dao` according to your need. I am using a repository for an example:

```
public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, ApplicationContext context) {
    this.repository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
}
```

And inorder to create the object of `JwtAuthenticationFilter`, you need `ApplicationContext` object and you can easily get it by autowiring.

```
@Autowired 
private ApplicationContext context;
```

Then

```
new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, context);
```

Now you can use the repository to get the `User` object.
Hope, it helps.

Comment: thx before, this is my filter, how can i inject the context?

public LoginFilter(final String url, final AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        logger.info("onLoginFilter");
    }

Comment: just add parameter ApplicationContext to your constructor just like I did above.

Comment: ok, the bean undefined for type appcontext

 this.repository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);

error:
The method getBean(Class<UserRepository>) is undefined for the type ApplicationContext

Comment: How are you accessing your database? Are you using Spring data jpa or dao? Replace context.getBean(UserRepository.class); according to your need.